# How to override css properties of Material UI components

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on project in which I have to use Material UI, just for simplicity, consider I am having a simple functional component in which I am having 2 Material UI components Button and Text Field

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

function RenderComponent(){
    return(
        <>
            <Button variant="contained">Contained</Button>
            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
        </>
    )
}

export default RenderComponent
```

Can anyone please tell me how to override the css properties of these 2 Material UI components.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, you can directly override the built-in `CSS` [class](https://v4.mui.com/api/button/#css) of an MUI component using the class name in your imported `CSS` file, for example in if you want to change the `Button` component's style, you can do this by applying your required `CSS` properties to `.MuiButton-root` class on your "CSS" file. Like bellow.

```
.MuiButton-root{
   color: white;
   height: 20px;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

You can also use the available `props` of a component, you can easily find them in their individual documentation [page](https://v4.mui.com/api/button/#props) of mui site.
Again you can use `makeStyles` or `styled` to style your component.
Here is an example to use `makeStyles` in your `Button` component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({

    root: {
          background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
          border: 0,
          borderRadius: 3,
          boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
          color: 'white',
          height: 48,
          padding: '0 30px',
        },
     });

function RenderComponent(){
    const classes = useStyles();
    return(
        <>
            <Button className={classes.root} variant="contained">Contained</Button>
            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
        </>
    )
}

export default RenderComponent
```

You can find more about styles [here.](https://v4.mui.com/styles/basics/#getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

Give them id's/classes and write your custom CSS for them. If it doesn't override the standard Material-UI styles, add the keyword [!important](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp). If you are using create-react-app, you can import CSS right to the file like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
```

If this doesn't help, that means Material-UI uses inline styles for the elements. In this case, you would have to write your CSS right into your components' attributes: like [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html). If it doesn't override standard styles, use !important again.